# Working with the results from an EXEC into a OUTER APPLY

Tags: t-sql, join, insert, exec, apply

I have the following TSQL where I'm trying to meaningfully supply the details of what tables within a database are taking up the most space. On it's own, I can use something like;

```
INSERT INTO #Data
   EXEC sp_spaceused N'tableNameHere'
```

And this works file. However, extending this to return info for all tables is problematic. The code;

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    tableName varchar(100),
    numberofRows varchar(100),
    reservedSize varchar(50),
    dataSize varchar(50),
    indexSize varchar(50),
    unusedSize varchar(50)
)
SELECT so.name, sp.*
    FROM dbo.sysobjects so
    OUTER APPLY (INSERT INTO #Data 
                    OUTPUT inserted.tableName, 
                           inserted.numberofRows,
                           inserted.reservedSize,
                           inserted.dataSize,
                           inserted.indexSize,
                           inserted.unusedSize
                    EXEC sp_spaceused name
                ) sp
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, N'IsUserTable') = 1
    ORDER BY sp.dataSize DESC, sp.indexSize DESC

    DROP TABLE #Data
```

But this results in the following error;

```
Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
```

I've double and triple checked that the insert list matches that of the result set, even by name but I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using OUTER APPLY, I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    tableName varchar(100),
    numberofRows varchar(100),
    reservedSize varchar(50),
    dataSize varchar(50),
    indexSize varchar(50),
    unusedSize varchar(50)
)

INSERT #Data
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''
```

Another option is to view the source code in `sp_spaceused` and write your own query which joins against a list of tables instead of handling one table at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is probably a misleading error message. I've never thought of using an OUTPUT do do an INSERT...EXEC as a subquery, use the results and have them for later. Unfortunately when I tried this, slightly modified, example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    tableName varchar(100),
    numberofRows varchar(100),
    reservedSize varchar(50),
    dataSize varchar(50),
    indexSize varchar(50),
    unusedSize varchar(50)
)

INSERT #Data
OUTPUT inserted.tableName, 
       inserted.numberofRows,
       inserted.reservedSize,
       inserted.dataSize,
       inserted.indexSize,
       inserted.unusedSize
exec sp_spaceused N'tblLeave'

DROP TABLE #Data
```

I got this error:

`Msg 483, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
The OUTPUT clause cannot be used in an INSERT...EXEC statement.`

I have a feeling that's partly why this syntax isn't behaving for you.